# Elementary equivalence between two structures

Tags: logic, model-theory

I'm working my way through Enderton and am stuck on the following exercise.

Take a language containing $\forall$, $=$, and the binary predicate $P$. Define the model $\frak{M}$ so that $\frak{M}= \mathbb{Z}$ and $(x,y)\in P^{\frak{M}}$ iff $|x-y|=1$.

I want to show that there exists some model $\frak{N}$ that is elementarily equivalent to $\frak{M}$ and that is not connected. Enderton defines connected as follows. For any two $a,b \in \frak{M}$, there is a path between them, i.e., a sequence $(p_0, p_1, \ldots, p_m)$ so that $p_0 =a$ and $p_m =b$ and $(p_j, p_{j+1}) \in P^{\frak{M}}$ for each $j$. Also, as usual, elementary equivalence means $\models_{\frak{N}} s$ iff $\models_{\frak{M}} s$ for any sentence $s$ in the language.

I'm given a suggestion to add two constant symbols to the language and write a sentence saying that they are "far apart". Then I apply compactness.

I honestly have no idea why this suggestion will work. Ultimately, I'm curious to see how this exercise is proved exactly. Also, I don't know any technical graph theory, so I'd appreciate answers that omit sophisticated terminology of that kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that compactness says:

> If $\Gamma$ is a set of sentences, and every finite subset of $\Gamma$ has a model, then $\Gamma$ has a model.

Our goal in an exercise like this is to do the following: find a set of sentences (in a larger language) which contain the theory of $\mathcal{M}$ (so any model's reduct to the original language will be $\equiv\mathcal{M}$), but which *also* include sentences describing a phenomenon which does not happen in $\mathcal{M}$.

For example, if $\mathcal{M}$ is $(\mathbb{N}; 1, +)$, a natural way to do this is to expand our language by a new constant $c$, and consider the set of sentences $\Gamma$ consisting of

- All sentences in the original language true of $\mathcal{M}$, and
- The sentence "$\neg(1+1+...+1=a)$" ($n$ $1$s) for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Then:

- Any finite subset $\Delta$ of $\Gamma$ has a model, in particular some expansion of $\mathcal{M}$; just make $a$ denote an element larger than any of the (finitely many!) $n$s such that "$\neg(1+1+...+1=a)$" ($n$ $1$s) is in $\Delta$.
- But $\mathcal{M}$ **cannot** be expanded to a model of all of $\Gamma$ - where could $a$ go?

So while $\Gamma$ has a model by Compactness, the *reduct to the original language* of any such model will be a structure elementarily equivalent to, but not isomorphic to, $\mathcal{M}$.

---

In the example you give, the phenomenon we want to add is two points that are infinitely far apart. To do this, we'll expand our language by *two* new constant symbols, $a$ and $b$, and add to the theory of $\mathcal{M}$ the sentences

- $\neg\exists x_1, . . ., x_n(P(a, x_1)\wedge P(x_1, x_2)\wedge . . . \wedge P(x_n,b))$ (that is, $a$ and $b$ are *at least $n$ edges apart*) for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Do you see why this collection of sentences is finitely consistent? And do you see why any model of this collection of sentences must have an underlying graph which is *not isomorphic to* $\mathcal{M}$?

Comment: This is great!. Just one clarification: doesn't the sentence $\neg\exists x_1, \ldots, x_n(P(a, x_2) \land P(x_1, x_2)\land \ldots \land P(x_n, b))$ mean here "there is no path of length $n$ between $a$ and $b$"? (Which cannot be true in a model in the original language for all of $\Gamma$).

Comment: @CuriousKid7 That's what I meant when I said $a$  and $b$ are at least nn edges apart. And it's not true that this can't be true in a(n expansion of a) model in the original language for all of $\Gamma$ - it just can't be true for any expansion of *the specific model $\mathcal{M}$.* The whole point of Compactness is that it *can* be true in some model.

Comment: Right that all makes sense. Thanks again!

Comment: One more question: Do we need to add the sentence for each natural $n$, or would it suffice to just add one sentence saying that $a,b$ are at least, say, $5$ edges apart? wouldn't the collection still be finitely consistent?

Comment: @CuriousKid7 As long as you have enough sentences - you need to say that they're at least $n$ apart *for arbitrarily large $n$* (or else you don't necessarily get something different from your starting structure).